# How can pass different ChartType from diffrant methods to the paramater to this CreateGraph() method?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Where I wrong suggest me.

I have two different methods, one is `CreateGraph`.

Example:

```
protected void PaiGraph_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CreateGraph() //pass SeriesChartType.Pie  
}

protected void BarGraph_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CreateGraph() //pass SeriesChartType.Bar
}
```

Call

```
public void CreateGraph()
{
    DataTable taskTable = (DataTable)Session["TaskTable"];
    int no = Convert.ToInt16("5");

    string[] x = new string[no];
    int[] y = new int[no];

    for (int j = 0; j < taskTable.Rows.Count; j++)
    {
            for (int i = 8; i < 9; i++)
            {
                x[j] = taskTable.Rows[j][i].ToString();
                y[j] = Convert.ToInt16(taskTable.Rows[j][i].ToString().Split(' ')[0]);
            }
    }

    Chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(x, y);
    Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;
    Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].Area3DStyle.Enable3D = false;
    Chart1.Legends[0].Enabled = true;
}
```

When we call `PaiGraph_Click()` it will pass `SeriesChartType.Pie` parameter to this `CreateGraph()` method, and `BarGraph_Click()` call it will pass `SeriesChartType.Bar` parameter to the `CreateGraph()` method .

How can pass?

Answer (score 0):

Change your CreateGraph() method to:

```
public void CreateGraph(SeriesChartType type){   
    if (type == SeriesChartType.Pie){
        // arrange data for pie chart
        Chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(x, y);
        Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].Area3DStyle.Enable3D = false;
        Chart1.Legends[0].Enabled = true;
    }
    else {
        //arrange data for barchart
        Chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(x, y);
        Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar;
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].Area3DStyle.Enable3D = false;
        Chart1.Legends[0].Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Then you change your calls in the on click to

```
 CreateGraph(SeriesChartType.Pie)
```

replace pie for bar in you call in BarGraph.Click

EDIT:

Alternatively, you could use a [switch statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx), but seems overkill for only 2 options.